# Get data from ListObject not made from code

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, listobject

In a VSTO Workbook,
I would like to get data from a ListObject made from Excel. So there is not such things like DataBinding in code.

What I would like to do is something like that :

```
var rows = ((DataTable)Globals.Feuil1.MyNamedListObject.DataSource).Rows
```

Unfortunately, here DataSource is null because, of course, it is not bound.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is for you to get the ListObject from the Workbook by name. This function below will return the ListObject by a string name. It iterates through all the worksheets and respective ListObjects comparing the names with the string you passed and if matches, return the ListObject. Hope it helps. Best regards.

```
'
' Find a Table in the Workbook by its String name
'
Function GetTable(strTable As String) As ListObject

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In WS.ListObjects
            If tbl.Name = strTable Then
                Set GetTable = tbl
                On Error GoTo 0
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Set GetTable = Nothing

End Function
```